# Event/ETL based Agent in OBIEE 11g

Tags: oracle11g, etl, agent, obiee

I have created an Agent in OBIEE 11g which kicks off at a specific time (8 am everyday). The problem is that sometimes by this time the underlying ETL process does not complete so the report kicked off by the agent shows inaccurate data. One way to rectify this is that I can reschedule the agent, i mean delay it by couple of hrs. But I am looking for event based triggering of agent. Like when my ETL completes then the agent should kick off. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe this question would be better of at https://dba.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 1):

You could set the Agent to have no schedule, and instead trigger it from your ETL batch on completion from a Web Service call [executeIBotNow](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e16364/methods.htm#CHDCDDAH), or with [saschinoke](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e10543/ssl.htm#BIESC749)

This blog article gives detail around the options (even if you're not using ODI, the concepts will still apply): http://www.rittmanmead.com/2012/01/bi-ee-11-1-1-5-calling-bi-ee-11g-agents-through-oracle-data-integrator-11g/

A last option would be to use a [Condition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e10544/conditions.htm#BABDFDFC) that the Agent checks before running, and schedule the Agent to run multiple times. It's not nearly as clean as the above options though.